Johnwood Electric Water Heater
I need to know if it is safe to shut off the electric heater switch from the main panel and also shut off the water supply

What makes you think it would not be?

Either/both the breaker for the water heater and/or the disconnect will work.
Shut off water after turning off the breaker/disconnect.  Turn on water and make sure the tank is full before turning on breaker/disconnect.
Never try draining the tank with the power to it on.

thanks for the response

@crip,  How did you discern that was what the OP wanted to do?  Are you psychic?

@RMDman  If about the last sentence, then just added as a precaution to OP and anybody else.  Draining is just one of a few reasons to turn off power and water to a tank.

@crip, you are psychic...I didn't get it at all.

@RMDman  Too bad it does not work for lotto tickets.
